# mini-app which makes use of GPS API and geo location

Tags: android, gps, location, geo

I have an assignment
•You have to develop a mini-app which makes use of GPS API available in Android or Windows platform to use the geo-location of the device
•First button in POI Entry screen is Take Photo. Until snap is taken, button should show Take Photo -PENDING. Pressing this button should invoke camera to take a snap. Once snap is taken, button should change to Take Photo –DONE
•The geo-location from photo is used as input into publicly available geo information to extract location information such as locality, town, city, district.
•Eg. If user is located at 19.15915°,72.97020°, entering 19.15915,72.97020 in a web query or any geo information site yields the results as shown below

I didnt get it. What kind of photo is he talking about here? How do I get longitude and lattitude fro from this photo? PLease guide me about this and a little help about how to proceed with programming would be apprecciated

Answer (score 0):

The first point says "**makes use of GPS API available in Android or Windows platform to use the geo-location of the device**". So geo information needs to be collected using devices's LocationManager ( Android). I dont think it is related to photo.

From my understanding, you can use (lat,long) and use reverseGeocode apis to obtain city,town,district information and then upload the photo to your server along with these information. or do whatever with these data ( PHOTO --> ( lat,long,city,town,district...etc) ) .

Answer (score 0):

You can get the latitude and longitude from the photo itself. The snapshot which you will take having attributes like gps latitude and gps longitude. So you have latitude and longitude, now you can easily get the current location by passing latitude and longitude as parameter to following url:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=latitude,longitude&sensor=true and parse the current location.